# Unable to resolve service for type 'BookEvent.Project.UserDomain.UoW.ICommentUnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'CommentAppService'.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-3.1

Hi I am Getting this error `BookEvent.Project.UserDomain.AppServices.ICommentAppService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: BookEvent.Project.UserDomain.AppServices.CommentAppService': Unable to resolve service for type 'BookEvent.Project.UserDomain.UoW.ICommentUnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'BookEvent.Project.UserDomain.AppServices.CommentAppService'.)` when I run my application. Since I not able to figure out what I am doing work. I have no idea how to resolve it. Can anybody help me please.

CommentAppService.cs

```
public class CommentAppService:AppService, ICommentAppService
    {
        private IMapper _mapper;
        private ICommentRepository _commentRepository;
        public CommentAppService(ICommentUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ICommentRepository commentRepository, IMapper mapper, IExceptionManager exceptionManager) : base(unitOfWork, exceptionManager)
        {

            this._mapper = mapper;
            this._commentRepository = commentRepository;
        }
   }
```

CommentUnitOfWork.cs

```
public class CommentUnitOfWork : UnitOfWork, ICommentUnitOfWork
    {
        public CommentUnitOfWork(BookDomainDbContext dbContext, IExceptionManager exceptionManager) : base(dbContext, exceptionManager)
        {

        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
   services.AddTransient<IUserAppService, UserAppService>();
   services.AddTransient<IEventAppService, EventAppService>();
   services.AddTransient<ICommentAppService, CommentAppService>();
```

CommentController.cs

```
 public class CommentController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ILogger<CommentController> _logger;
        private readonly ICommentAppService _commentAppService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public CommentController(ILogger<CommentController> logger, ICommentAppService commentAppService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _commentAppService = commentAppService;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateComment(CommentDTO item)
        {
            item.Date = DateTime.Now;
            var result = _commentAppService.Create(item);
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                this._logger.LogInformation(result.MainMessage.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                Message = $"About page visited at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()}";
                this._logger.LogError(Message);
                return View("CreateEvent");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        public IActionResult CreateComment()
        {
            return View(new CommentViewModel());
        }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The exception alredy tells you exacly what is going wrong:

`Unable to resolve service for type 'BookEvent.Project.UserDomain.UoW.ICommentUnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'BookEvent.Project.UserDomain.AppServices.CommentAppService'.)`

So when DI is trying to instanciate `CommentAppService` it is looking for `ICommentUnitOfWork` because it is expected in the constructor of `CommentAppService` but it cannot find an implementation for `ICommentUnitOfWork`.

In your startup you are registering three things

```
services.AddTransient<IUserAppService, UserAppService>();
services.AddTransient<IEventAppService, EventAppService>();
services.AddTransient<ICommentAppService, CommentAppService>();
```

but none of them is `ICommentUnitOfWork`. Just register it in the startup and it will work fine.